# $E\left[ \max(X_1,\cdots,X_n) \right]$ with i.i.d. $X_i\sim Exp(\lambda) $

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

**Question.** Let $ X_1,\cdots,X_n $ be i.i.d. random variables with exponential distributions, $ X_i\sim Exp(\lambda) $. Find $E\left[  \max(X_1,\cdots,X_n) \right]$.

**My approach.** Let's find a recursive relation in terms of $ n $. Define
\begin{align*}
&Y_1 = X_1,\\ 
&Y_2 = \max(X_1,X_2),\\
&\vdots\\
&Y_n = \max(X_1,\cdots,X_n).
 \end{align*}
We have the relation
\begin{align*}
  &Y_n = \begin{cases}
  X_n\ &{\rm if}\ X_n>Y_{n-1},\\
  Y_{n-1}\ &{\rm otherwise},
  \end{cases}\implies Y_n = Y_{n-1} + (X_n-Y_{n-1})1_{\{X_n>Y_{n-1}\}}\\
  &\implies E[Y_n] = E[Y_{n-1}] + E[(X_n-Y_{n-1})1_{\{X_n>Y_{n-1}\}}].
 \end{align*}
Now, using the independence of $ X_n $ and $ Y_{n-1} $, we have
\begin{align*}
E[(X_n-Y_{n-1})1_{\{X_n>Y_{n-1}\}}]& = \int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}(x-y)1_{\{x>y\}}f_{X_{n}}(x)f_{Y_{n-1}}(y)\ dx dy\\
& = \int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{y}^{\infty}(x-y)f_{X_{n}}(x) dx\ f_{Y_{n-1}}(y) dy\\
& = \int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{\exp(-\lambda y)}{\lambda} f_{Y_{n-1}}(y) dy
 \end{align*}
So,
\begin{align*}
  E[Y_n] = E[Y_{n-1}] + \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\exp(-\lambda y)}{\lambda} f_{Y_{n-1}}(y) dy.
 \end{align*}
But I do not know what to do with the inetgral.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3560742/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3841157/321264.

Comment: Also this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3458175/407165 combined with this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/93098/407165

Comment: Thank you all for the help